# Which SR momentum formulas carry over to GR?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, momentum, metric-tensor

In special relativity, the four-momentum of a massive particle is given by
$$
P^\mu = m \frac{\mathrm{d} x^\mu}{\mathrm{d} \tau} = m \, U^\mu. \tag{1}
$$

Since $\mathrm{d} \tau = \gamma^{-1} \mathrm{d} t$, we get $U^\mu = (\gamma c, \gamma \vec{v})$ and so $P^\mu = (\gamma m c, \gamma m \vec{v})$. Calculating the square of $P$ reveals what invariant $P^2$ is (+,-,-,- metric)
$$
P^\mu P_\mu = (P^0)^2 - p^2 = m^2 \gamma^2 (c^2 - v^2) = ( m c )^2. \tag{2}
$$

By mass-energy equivalence and looking at $P^0$ in the rest frame of the particle, we see, that $P^0 = E/c$ and thus
$$
E = \sqrt{(mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2}. \tag{3}
$$

Now, I have some trouble carrying this over to general relativity. I am fine with (1), as that's just a definition. However, I am not completely sure we can just use $\gamma$ as the factor when comparing frames. Does the formula $P^\mu = (\gamma m c, \gamma m \vec{v})$ survive? We know, that $P^\mu P_\mu$ is now way more complicated than just $(P^0)^2 - p^2$, since the metric isn't just diag(1,-1,-1,-1)
$$
P^2 = g_{\mu \nu} P^\mu P^\nu \neq (P^0)^2 - p^2 \tag{4}
$$
so it seems we need to abandon the factor $\gamma$, possibly.

1. is $P^2 = (mc)^2$ a definition? If not, how do we know this in general relativity? (I know that the square of a 4-vector must be an invariant, so the only sensible choice is $(mc)^2$, but that doesn't feel like a "proof")
2. how do we show that $P^0 = E/c$, since we can't use the same line of reasoning we did in SR?

Even though I took both SR and GR, it left me feeling like there's some circular reasoning involved in this.

Comment: $\tau$ is defined by $d \tau^2 = d s^2 = g_{\mu\nu} d x^\mu dx^\nu$ which implies that $g_{\mu\nu} U^\mu U^\nu = +1$. Energy is not defined by $P^0$. Rather it is defined by $E = g_{\mu\nu} t^\mu U^\nu$ where $t^\mu$ is the timelike Killing vector of the background geometry.

Comment: @Prahar thanks, that is very useful! I see now that $P^2 = m^2$ is a consequence of the definition of $\mathrm{d} \tau$. Why is $P^0 = E$ in FRW metric? At least we used it to derive the relation between the scale factor $a$ and the photon energy (I know this question was about a massive particle and now I'm bringing a massless particle into the picture). But does a timelike Killing vector of the FRW metric even exist? If it does not, how can we even speak of energy (of a single particle) and why is it assumed to be $P^0$? How would we properly derive photon redshift?

Comment: The $E$ that I defined is conserved if and only if $t^\mu$ is a Killing vector. This is not the case for the FRW metric so $E$ is not conserved. Note that in the FRW case, $t^\mu=(1,0,0,0)$ and $g_{tt}=1$ so it follows that $E=U^0$. Another thing to note is Maxwell theory is conformal in four dimensions so one can define a conserved quantity like energy if we have a timelike _conformal_ Killing vector which FRW does have.

Comment: @Prahar but why is $E$ defined as $g_{\mu \nu} t^\mu P^\mu = g_{0 \mu} P^\mu$? I understand that in the usual cases this just gives $P^0 = E$, if $g$ is not diagonal or the $g_{00}$ term isn't 1, it may get complicated, but where does this definition of $E$ come from, physically?

Comment: The $E$ I have defined is conserved if $t^\mu$ is a Killing vector and $U^\mu$ is tangent to a geodesic.